# Log parsing alert in stackdriver from textPayload?

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, monitoring, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm little bit stuck with alerting in stackdriver. My goal is to make an alert from the parsing log from MySQL error. I have `textPayload: "2020-06-24T17:25:05.766410Z 332837 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 1073741816 bytes)"` messages and i need do alert, when i have 5 messages like that. But i'm stuck with metric, when i'm trying to create and setup i got errors with reg exp. Maybe i need other way to configure that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [query editor and try](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries):

```
resource.type="gce_instance"
textPayload.message=~"/usr/sbin/mysqld: Out of memory"
```

This will match all the log entries and then you can create a log-based metric that will [count a log entries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/counter-metrics) and then an [alert](http://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting) you want (like on the below picture);
[image]

When creating an [alerting policy](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui) make sure that field `agregator` is set to `sum` and `period` is set to whatever period you need. If you set it to 10 minutes if there will be just 4 errors alert won't be triggered. Keep that in mind. Uless they are generated in a very short periods of time but it's something that's specific to your case.

[image]

Configuration part should looks like this in my case:
[image]

On the other pages select alerting channel etc (pretty clear) and save the alert.

After completion your alert should look like this (I've created a metric & alert specifically for this exaple):
[image]

I've triggered an alert on purpose and got an email after about 2 minutes (which is typical) after the incident.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i don't have jsonPayload.message, i have - textPayload:

Comment: Change the `jsonPayload` to `textPayload`.

Comment: not working for some reason. this showing me needed records in log viewer.
resource.type="gce_instance"
textPayload=~"/usr/sbin/mysqld: Out of memory"
but when i save metric i cant see any graf.

Comment: You will see the chart after you create an alert from the metric. I've updated my answer with the picture how to do it.

Comment: Works, thank you for your updated answer. I used Count method in metric instead of Distribution (in my question metric was configured to Distribution). After i wait about 5 min i saw graf, after that i configured alert and it works.

Comment: Great to hear that !